# Having Issue Looping Through a Large Range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This code loops through a given range and converts each value to the short month name. It works great on small ranges but I wrote it for a dataset I get on a regular basis that is well over 100,000 rows. It still works on the full range but it takes a very long time and looks like it crashes but if I wait about 5 minutes it works.

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

```
Sub ConvertToMonth()

Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Cell In selectedRange
       Cell.Value = MonthName(Cell.Value, True)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome @WannabeDev, why do you require VBA for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the read/ write speed to the front end range in Excel. The best way to approach handling large data sets is to use an array. First, store your data set to an array, manipulate the array, then output the array. Much like what I have done below:

```vb
Sub ConvertToMonth()

    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    arr = selectedRange.Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LBound(arr,1) To UBound(arr,1)
       arr(i,1) = MonthName(arr(i,1), True)
    Next i

    selectedRange.Value = arr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Damn Dean that worked like a charm. You rock man. Much appreciated. Looks like I'm going to have to do some digging on arrays.

Comment: @WannabeDev I teach all my juniors the 3 Pillars to VBA are arrays, dictionaries and collections! Happy learning!

Comment: @Dean, I could recognize that after I tested the Arrays compared to the Collections( of cells within the selection), I got 23s speed difference for 1000 rows. The Array is very very quick (y)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop here at all. Just apply the format to the entire range all at once

---

```
SelectedRange.NumberFormat = "mmm"
```

Comment: I prefer this as well as it won't override the value of the selection!

Comment: This may work and is much simpler to write but I already implemented the solution from @Dean. Thank for thinking of me though.

Answer (score 2):

Except if you really need to do this in VBA, I think it's better for you to use the Excel build-in functions.
In the screenshot below, I used the following formula for C3 to C31 to get the Short name of a giving date month:

```
=TEXT(A3,"MMM")
```

[image]

It is very quick and avoid VBA's complications if designing it is still a challenge.

Let me know if this meets your need!

> **NB:** what I saw as dangerous with your VBA Function as well is that **It is Destructive**, I mean **you have no way to Undo it after you fire it up** and it is overwritting the selection **regardless of its content**. However, from Excel, you still can undo it. But it's up to you

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I was doing and after about the 100th time of creating a new column, writing the formula, and copying/pasting the results in the original column I was hoping for a better way. Dean gave me a perfect solution.

Comment: Wishing you all the best ;)

Comment: @WannabeDev You don't have to copy/paste formulas, just use a Table (List object).  What you described is as simple as typing your formula in the first cell of the first adjacent column to your Table and pressing "Enter".  The Table will add the column and populate the formula through the whole new Table column.

Comment: @WannabeDev, what I saw as dangerous with your VBA Function as well is that **It is Destructive**, I mean you have no way to Undo it after you fire it up. However, from Excel, you still can undo it. But it's up to you

Comment: I recommend the suggestion of @FrankBall to use a Table and the operation will be automatic as you change the first Value.

Comment: Appreciate all the great comments guys but this data set is well over 100,000 rows and ~30 columns. This raw data then feeds about 15 tabs with 3 pivot tables each. Adding another column to the raw data and changing all the references in the pivots (which I get pre-made from someone else) would just be too much effort.